# Create a separator

Tags: excel, vba, row

I want to create a colored line after each execution of this code between each execution or to color the last section.
In the code below, how can you create a colored blank row at the end of the operation?

```
Sub CopyHighlightedTransactions()
Dim mycell As Range
Dim myrange As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Set myrange = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("a2:a1000")
myrange.Interior.Pattern = xlnon

Dim mc As Range
Dim my As Range
Set my = Worksheets("sheet4").Range("a2:a1000")
my.Interior.Pattern = xlnon
For Each mc In my
  For i = 1 To 10
    If mc.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(my, i) Then
      mc.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
      mc.Resize(1, 16).Cut Destination:= _
            Worksheets("sheet5").Range("a1").Offset(Worksheets("sheet5").Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    End If

  Next
Next mc

Worksheets("sheet5").Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

I want to create a colored line after each execution of this code between each execution or to color the last section.

Comment: What code should I write to create a colored blank line?

Comment: If by "create a colored line after each execution" you mean do do it in `Worksheets("sheet5")` you may place some code lines just above `End Sub`. Something as `With Worksheets("sheet5").Range("A" & .rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` `.cells(1).value = "."`  `.EntireRow.Color = vbBlack` `End With`. Four code lines. If you place **a blank line**, it will be overwritten on the next run. So, the above code places only a dot in the first cell of the row.

Comment: It gives an error in the .rows.count section

Comment: Yes, there were two mistakes. I initially tried `With Worksheets("sheet5")`. Anyhow, it is difficult to write more than a code line here. I will create a `Sub` to be called by your code and post it as an answer. In fact, will adapt your code to do all the job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the adapted code. It calls `markLast` which colors in black the interior of the empty row after the last one:

```
Sub CopyHighlightedTransactions()
 Dim mycell As Range, myrange As Range, lastrow As Long
 Dim ws2 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, ws5 As Worksheet

 Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet2")
 Set ws4 = Worksheets("sheet4")
 Set ws5 = Worksheets("sheet5")

 Set myrange = ws2.Range("a2:a1000")
 myrange.Interior.Pattern = xlNone 'supposing that you do not need any pattern...


 Dim mc As Range, my As Range
 Set my = ws4.Range("a2:a1000")
 my.Interior.Pattern = xlNone 

 For Each mc In my
    For i = 1 To 10
        If mc.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(my, i) Then
          mc.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
          mc.Resize(1, 16).Cut Destination:= _
                ws5.Range("a1").Offset(ws5.rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next
 Next mc

 ws5.Columns.AutoFit

 'color the interiror of the empty row after the last one in black:
 markLast ws5
End Sub

Sub markLast(ws As Worksheet)
     With ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .Value = "."
        .EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbBlack
     End With
End Sub
```

If `xlnon` is not a custom pattern, it should be `xlNone` if you need to clear the pattern. To be none... In such a case, please write `Option Explicit` on top of the module (in the declarations area). It will force you to declare all variables and **it will warn you in case of a typo**.

And take care of the code indentation. Without it, if the code becomes complex it would be very difficult to understand and debug it.